# How to do Perl regex search-and-replace with indeterminate occurrances?

Tags: regex, perl, replace

In a text file I have some variable declarations, say:

```
long  foo0,
      foo1,
      foo2 ;
long  foo3;
short foo4;
short foo5, foo6 ;
long  foo7, foo8 ;
```

I want to use Perl to add a suffix "_r" to all "long" type variables, viz. foo0/1/2/3/7/8, and the expected output is:

```
long  foo0_r,
      foo1_r,
      foo2_r ;
long  foo3_r;
short foo4;
short foo5, foo6 ;
long  foo7_r, foo8_r ;
```

However, I can only come up with the following snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    #apply regex match and replace
    s/(long\s+)(\w+)(\s*;)/$1$2_r$3/g;
    #print current line. 
    print;
}

##inlined data filehandle for testing. 
__DATA__
long  foo0,
      foo1,
      foo2 ;
long  foo3;
short foo4;
short foo5, foo6 ;
long  foo7, foo8 ;
```

It only worked for foo3, but not other "long" foos. The trick is that the syntax is not a fixed one; rather, there might be an indeterminate number of declarations between "long" and ";", seperated by ","s. Can anyone provide some hints on the code?

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: Thx; already updated my original post.

Comment: @katyusza You could try `s/(long\s+)(\w+)(,\s+\w+)*(\s*;)/$1$2_r$3_r$4/g`, but I am very unsure how that would handle the third capture group. Try it and let me know, I am curious to see if it will replace `$3` with `$3_r` in the case of multiple elements.

Comment: You may be better off doing it in 2 steps, one to see if it's a long, and a second to rename all the enements in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the record separator using `$/` and use negative lookbehind to match all words that arent `long` in that record.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

$/=";";
while (<DATA>) {
    s/(\w+\b)(?<!\blong)/$1_r/g if /^\s*long/;
    print;
}

##inlined data filehandle for testing.
__DATA__
long  foo0,
      foo1,
      foo2 ;
long  foo3;
short foo4;
short foo5, foo6 ;
long  foo7, foo8 ;
```

Produces

```
long  foo0_r,
      foo1_r,
      foo2_r ;
long  foo3_r;
short foo4;
short foo5, foo6 ;
long  foo7_r, foo8_r ;
```

Comment: Yep, it really worked! But shouldn't negative lookbehind work this way? -- (?<!a)b -- matches "b" that is not preceded by "a" -- Shouldn't we put the stuff after "(?<!"? Why are you putting the stuff before "(?<!"?

Comment: @katyusza `Shouldn't we put the stuff after "(?<!"`, try it! Look [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for more info

Comment: I tried some other flavors: `s/(?<!\blong)(\w+\b)/$1_r/g if /^\s*long/;`, and `s/(?<!\blong)(\w+\b)/$2_r/g if /^\s*long/;`, both returned weird results. Seems the code does not allow any improvisation!

Comment: @katyusza It should, what are you trying to do ?

Comment: Would you mind sharing your ideas beneath the `s/(\w+\b)(?<!\blong)/$1_r/g if /^\s*long/;` code? I now know it DOES work but I do not know WHY or HOW it works. How is your regex related to the multiple variable declaration over multiple lines?

Comment: My original intention is to process Verilog code, and do conversions from `reg d1, d2;` to `reg d1_tmr, d2_tmr;`.

Comment: @katyusza It did work how i thought just got a bit confused. So basically it checks that `\w+\b` matches and from there checks backwards from that position(at the end of that match) to ensure that `\blong` is not the string before that position.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest:

```
if (m/^long\b/) {
    s/(\s\w+)/${1}_r/g;
}
```

---

**Edit** for updated question: To support multiline declarations, you can first set `$/ = ';'` (so that "lines" will be separated by `;` rather than newlines . . . it's a bit of a hack, but it means that each iteration of the while-loop will get a single declaration instead of a single normal line). Then you need to support whitespace before the `long` keyword at the beginning of the "line" (since it will have the newline after the previous declaration's semicolon), by writing `m/^\s*long\n/` instead of just `m/^long\n/`. Lastly, you need to support *not* converting `long` to `long_r`, which is a bit trickier now. (Earlier, we were relying on the presence of `\s` to distinguish it, but that won't work anymore.) One way to do that last part is to actually remove the `long`, and print it, *before* doing the replacement that adds `_r`.

Overall:

```
$/ = ';';
while (<DATA>) {
    if (s/(\s*long)\b//) {
        print $1;
        s/(\w+)/${1}_r/g;
    }
    print;
}
```

Comment: Thanks~! The code is ok for variables in the same line, but actually the variables in one "long" declaration may span multiple lines; any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** forgot to handle the commas. This is now fix;

This is one way to do it

```
while ( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    # split line into type and vars
    my ( $type, @vars ) = split(/[\s,;]+/, $line);
    # if type is long, append '_r' to vars 
    if ( lc $type eq 'long' ) {
        @vars = map { $_ . '_r' } @vars;
    }   
    # join it all back together
    print join(' ', $type, join(', ', @vars)) . ";\n";
}   

__DATA__
long  foo0, foo1, foo2 ;
long  foo3;
short foo4;
short foo5, foo6 ;
```

**UPDATE**

Updated solution that supports vars on multiple lines...

```
my $state;
while ( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    $state .= $line;
    if ( $line =~ /;/ ) {
        if ( $state =~ /long/ ) {
            $state =~ s/(\s\w+)/$1_r/g;
        }
        print $state;
        undef $state;
    }
}

__DATA__
long  foo0,
      foo1,
      foo2 ;
long  foo3;
short foo4;
short foo5, foo6 ;
long  foo7, foo8 ;
```

OUTPUT

```
long foo0_r,
     foo1_r,
     foo2_r ;
long foo3_r;
short foo4;
short foo5, foo6 ;
long foo7_r, foo8_r ;
```

Comment: I would recommend splitting on multiple spaces than just one. Especially since there are 2 spaces after `long`.

Comment: The proposed code gives result: long foo0,_r foo1,_r foo2_r; Seems the "," should be used for splitting as well?

Comment: Fixed issue with the comma's. I didn't even see them!

Comment: Your code is based on line-based approach; what if the "long" variable declaration may span multiple lines? Sorry I forgot to put this scenario into my first post. ;-(

Answer (score 0):

I would split the line by \s comma and semicolon , test for long being the first word, then iterate over rest of the words and append _r and reconstruct the line.